# Error when using unserialize() in php when check isset of item array()?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$text = 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s:18:"nokiainternal_ver1";s:10:"user_agent";s:13:"NokiaInternal";s:9:"fall_back";s:13:"nokia_generic";}';
$text = unserialize($text);
if(isset($text['model_name'])) {
   $text['model_name'] = 'Nokia'; 
}
echo $text['model_name'];
echo $text['user_agent'];
```

But result error `Notice: Undefined index: model_name ...` How to fix it ?

Comment: what exactly were you planning to do? providing a default value?

Comment: Your unserialized array is `Array ( [id] => nokiainternal_ver1 [user_agent] => NokiaInternal [fall_back] => nokia_generic )`, there is no key as `model_name`.

Answer (score 2):

The below code:

```
if(isset($text['model_name'])) {
   $text['model_name'] = 'Nokia'; 
}
```

Checks if `model_name` is set and if it is, sets it to "Nokia"

This means you are not setting the key `model_name` to anything, which is causing your `Undefined index` error.

Try:

```
if(!isset($text['model_name'])) {
   $text['model_name'] = 'Nokia'; 
}
```

Comment: @Micheal Robinson: result is a white page

Comment: White page means you have a code error - probably a syntax error. The answer looks fine - so check you've copied / pasted correctly?

Comment: @HaiTruong Put `ini_set('display_errors'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file. This will cause error messages to be displayed.